# Dustjs Recursion Template Error

Tags: recursion, dust.js

When trying to use recursion, i'm noticing inconsistencies and I'm not sure exactly why.

Using the recursion test on http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html (core test/recursion), i get different results for the following examples but I should receive the same results.

Example 1: 
Template: `{name}{~n}{#kids}{>recursion:./}{/kids}`

Data:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "kids": [{
        "name": "1.1",
        "kids": [{
            "name": "1.1.1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Result:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
```

Example 2:
Template: `{name}{~n}{#kidsa}{>recursion:./}{/kidsa}`

Data:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "kidsa": [{
        "name": "1.1",
        "kidsa": [{
            "name": "1.1.1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Result:

```
1
1.1
```

I would expect Example 2 results to be the same as Example 1 since it has the same structure as Example one only with the attribute kids changed to kidsa. Please let me know if this is expected behavior and how I can obtain the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`recursion` is the name of a pre-cached template. ([coreText.js:210](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/dust_files/coreTests.js))

The edited template always has the name 'demo' so the following template will work as expected.

```
{name}{~n}{#kidsa}{>demo:./}{/kidsa}
```

[image: ChromeConsole]